# repeated element on all pages of an access 2010 form

Tags: database, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an access 2010 form with more than five different pages ("tabs", access calls them pages). These are mainly used to illustrate the fields with different pictures and have a different set of fields on each page. However, some fields (mostly in the form of comboboxes) and other elements are repeated on each page.
Is there a way to place these and format them just once? Or do you have to do it manually (or by VBA code) for each page separately? Does something like a master page or “slide master” as used in powerpoint exist for MS access 2010 forms with more than one page?
I hope I was specific enough. I look forward to your answers.

Cheers,

Sven

Comment: can you take them out of each tab and place them above all the tabs?  Or is the idea that they need to be on each tab, but they're the same across tabs?  If they're the same across tabs, you can put them in a subform.

Answer (score 1):

Go to design view. Firstly, drag the fields that are being repeated, outside the tab. Copy the field(Click on it and hit Ctrl C). Click on the tab option. Go to the specific page on the tab where you want it, and right click and paste. That should do it. Now, it shouldn't repeat. Make sure you've right clicked on a white surface inside the page inside the tab option.

Comment: Thanks a lot Beth and Billy. I just copied the common fields (like you said Billy) from one tab on the form (outside that tab) and dragged it over the tab again. That did the job. Once you gave me these solutions it was kind of obvious. Thanks again. Best wishes, Sven